# How to find the average diameter of the drops, which are superimposed on a strip of size 260 mm x 6.2 mm using image processing?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

How to find the average diameter of the drops in an image. The drops on the image are raindrops, and the **strip** on which drops are superimposed has a size of **260 mm x 6.2 mm**. This strip length and breadth could be considered a reference (perspective) size and can be used to measure the drop diameter or length of the x and y axes in mm.
Also, how to label each drop with its diameter?

[image]

```
image = cv2.imread("1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# show it

# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# draw all contours

for contour in contours:
    if (cv2.contourArea(contour) < 3000) & (cv2.contourArea(contour) > 4):
        image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (1, 1, 1), 1)

        circles = image.copy()
        num_circles = len(contours)
        ave = 0
        rds = []
        center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
        cx = int(round(center[0]))
        cy = int(round(center[1]))
        rr = int(round(radius))
        # draw enclosing circle over beads
    #     cv2.circle(circles, (cx,cy), rr, (1,1,1), 1)
        # cumulate radii for average
        ave = ave + radius
        rds.append(rr)

# print average radius
ave_radius = ave / num_circles
print("average radius:", ave_radius)
print ("number of circles:", num_circles)

cv2.imwrite('beads_circles.jpg', circles)
plt.imshow(circles)
plt.show()
```

Here is the output

[image: output]

Comment: So what is the issue?  Does your code not work? Do you get any messages?

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, it does, but, I want to add labels of diameters on it.. and i want to calculate the actual diameter. If strip size is 260mm*16mm, then accordingly can we calculate the diameter

Comment: what prevents you from doing that? can we assume elementary arithmetic? ratios? cross-multiplication? related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71779539/how-to-find-width-height-and-diameter-of-the-drops-in-an-image-using-image-proc

Comment: Are you getting your radius in pixels correctly now? If so, then `X radius in mm = radius in pixels * (width of image in mm / width of image in pixels)`. Likewise for height of image to get Y radius in mm.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, yes we can assume elemantry arithmetic ratios.

Comment: Dear @fmw42, I am not sure how to do that! That's why I posted a question here

Comment: I have given you the formula above to do the computation once you have the radius in pixels. Measure the width and height of the image in mm and the width and height in pixels. Then multiply the ratio of (width in mm / width in pixels) * radius in X direction in pixels.  Similarly for the radius in Y direction in pixels times the ratio of (height in mm / height in pixels)

Comment: Your width in mm = 260 and width of the image is 500. So multiply your radius in pixels * (260/500).  The height in mm is 16.2 and height of the image is 64. So multiply your radius in pixels * (16.2/64).

Comment: Thank you @fmw42, I have done that, and I guess it is coming okay. There was a mistake in the question about width. The width is actually 6.2, not 16.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import glob
import os

img = cv2.imread("pip_ims/52.png")

image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
dia_mm = []
for contour in contours:
    #image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (1, 1, 1), 3)
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    dia = 2*(area/np.pi)**(0.5) # calculating diameter from area
    print(dia)
    diamm = dia*(6.2/64) # converting diameter from pixels to mm
    dia_mm.append(diamm)
    print(diamm)
diameter = list(filter(lambda num: num != 0, dia_mm)) # removing zeros
diameter = np.array(diameter)
print(diameter.mean(), diameter.max(), diameter.min())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your scale factors in X and Y are not consistent.  260/500=0.52, but 6.2/64=0.096875.  That is quite different. So you may want to compute the radius (or diameter) in X and Y and multiply by the corresponding ratio.